# I have valid a View in my views.py file but still giving me error 'not a valid view function'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am using Django 2.1
`

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect,get_object_or_404
from .forms import PostUrl
from .models import UrlLink

def total_url(request):
    urls=UrlLink.objects.all()
    return render(request,'core/shorturl.html',{'urls':urls})

def url_list(request,pk):
    url = get_object_or_404(UrlLink,pk=pk)
    return render(request,'core/url_detail.html',{'url':url})


def url_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form=PostUrl(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            url=form.save()
            return redirect('total_url')
    else:
        form=PostUrl()
        return render(request,'core/url_list.html',{'form':form})
```

`

but when I submit the form I am getting the error
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'total_url' not found. 'total_url' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Here is my url file
`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.url_new,name='url_list'),
    path('<int:pk>/',views.url_list,name='url_detail'),
    path('all/',views.total_url,name='totalUrl')
]
```

`
I figured out it was a typo mistake

Comment: Please share your urls.

Comment: @art06 yes I updated this question please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view name is `totalUrl`, not `total_url`.

Answer (score 1):

Django redirect can take:

1. the model’s get_absolute_url() function will be called.
2. A view name, possibly with arguments: reverse() will be used to reverse-resolve the name.
3. An absolute or relative URL, which will be used as-is for the redirect location.

Clearly, your are using the view names, the problem here is you need to specify your view name in your URLPatterns, but not directly use view function as your view names.

for example:
path('books/', views.BookListView.as_view(), name='books'), view name here is 'books ' in this condition.

Comment: I think I have added path in my url section and edited this question too. Have a look